# Iframing Redirection?

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iframe in my page, but the problem is that it redirects to another page, and that breaks the frame. Can I do something to load the redirected page in the same frame?

Edit : Redirection is favorable. Page is designed to redirect but inside frame only.

code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>StarBucks $100 Gift Card</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Starbucks gift card" />
    <meta name="description" content="Enter Email to Win $100 StarBucks Gift Card" />
    <style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="http://tnktrck.com/?a=9480&c=5164&s1=" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
        <p>Click <a href="http://tnktrck.com/?a=9480&c=5164&s1=">here</a>! (Your browser does not support iframes)</p>
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Url A redirect to B --- But this should happen inside frame. but it break frame.

Also Url in Example is for us only.

Answer (score 1):

The page you're trying to load probably has framebusting code, specifically designed to stop people trying to do what you're doing.

Comment: +1. And there is nothing can be done about it short of creating your own browser that explcitly implements security issues (which is one of the reasons inner IFrame must be able to do full page navigation for login /authentication pages).

Comment: No it doesn't have any frame buster. It is designed for framing only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe like this

```
<body>
<iframe name="order" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="" >
</iframe>
<body>
```

JS:

```
<script>
 window.order.location.href="";
</script>
```